# How would I get the context of a RecyclerView List Item?

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase, android-recyclerview

I am new to Firebase and RecyclerViews and I am trying to get a list of ingredients from my Firebase Database and I want to create checkboxes for every item I retrieve from the database. I got as far as creating a RecyclerView and adapter for my Firebase Query but binding lists from the query doesn't seem to be covered anywhere I could find.

Please find below the code for putting the data into the recycler view as well as the layout files being used for the recycler view.

[Data being retrieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLTFa.png)
that I want to display the *original* field of my object as checkboxes

ShoppingListFragment.kt

```
class ShoppingListFragment : Fragment() {



    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        //Enable Firestore logging
        FirebaseFirestore.setLoggingEnabled(true)

        //Firestore
        firestore = Firebase.firestore

        // Get recipes that the user has liked up to ${LIMIT}
        query = firestore.collection("recipes").whereArrayContains(
            "plannedBy",
            Firebase.auth.uid.toString()
        )
            .orderBy("name", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
            .limit(LIMIT.toLong())


        // Init the adapter to hold the recipe objects.
        adapter = object : ShoppingListAdapter(query) {
            override fun onDataChanged() {
                if (itemCount == 0) {
                    shoppingListRecycler.visibility = View.GONE
                    viewEmpty.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                } else {
                    shoppingListRecycler.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    viewEmpty.visibility = View.GONE
                }

            }

            override fun onError(e: FirebaseFirestoreException) {
                // Show a snackbar on errors
                view?.let {
                    Snackbar.make(
                        it,
                        "Error: check logs for info.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                }
            }

        }
         ...

    }
...

}
```

ShoppingListAdapter.kt

```
open class ShoppingListAdapter(query: Query) :
    FirestoreAdapter<ShoppingListViewHolder>(query) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ShoppingListViewHolder {
        return ShoppingListViewHolder(
            ItemShoppingListBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ShoppingListViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getSnapshot(position))
    }


}
```

ShoppingListViewHolder.kt

```
class ShoppingListViewHolder(val binding: ItemShoppingListBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    fun bind(snapshot: DocumentSnapshot) {

        val recipe = snapshot.toObject<Recipe>() ?: return

        binding.listTitle.text = recipe.name
        if(recipe.ingredients.size > 1) {
            binding.shoppingListItem.text = recipe.ingredients[0].original

            for(i in 1 until recipe.ingredients.size) {
                val checkBox = CheckBox() //Not sure what to put here as the context for my recyclerview List Item

                checkBox.text = recipe.ingredients[i].original
                checkBox.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

                binding.shoppingListContainer.addView(checkBox)
            }


        } else {
            binding.shoppingListItem.text = recipe.ingredients[0].original
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried passing a context parameter through ShoppingListViewHolder.kt and in turn adding that parameter to the adapter and so forth like so.

```
class ShoppingListViewHolder(val binding: ItemShoppingListBinding, val context: Context) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
   
    fun bind(snapshot: DocumentSnapshot) {

        val recipe = snapshot.toObject<Recipe>() ?: return

        binding.listTitle.text = recipe.name
        if(recipe.ingredients.size > 1) {
            binding.shoppingListItem.text = recipe.ingredients[0].original

            for(i in 1 until recipe.ingredients.size) {
                val checkBox = CheckBox(context) 
            ...

}
```

ShoppingListFragment.kt

```
        // Init the adapter to hold the recipe objects.
        adapter = object : ShoppingListAdapter(query, requireContext()) {
            override fun onDataChanged() {
                if (itemCount == 0) {
                    shoppingListRecycler.visibility = View.GONE
                    viewEmpty.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                } else {
                    shoppingListRecycler.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    viewEmpty.visibility = View.GONE
                }

            }

            override fun onError(e: FirebaseFirestoreException) {
                // Show a snackbar on errors
                view?.let {
                    Snackbar.make(
                        it,
                        "Error: check logs for info.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                }
            }

        }
```

But all that did was create a huge amount of white space between entries. After some debugging, it looks like passing the context from the fragment gave it the MainActivity context. I'm not too sure where to go from here and any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted **almost 300 lines of code** for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've reduced the amount of code from my question so it's isolates only on the recyclerview portion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `binding.root.context` except passing `context`

Comment: Thank you that did it!